# about AWS product api : how to get the product selectIndex(category)?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I use Amazon Product Advertising API search product.

but when i don't setting **SearchIndex** parameter (default ALL), i can't use sort parameter.

so,
i need get the product **category**, can only setting the **SearchIndex** parameter.

it's should is this : [**category** -> **searchIndex**]

this idea is feasible?

doc sources :

[API tester page](http://webservices.amazon.cn/scratchpad/index.html)

friends have what good idea? thx